# How to convert data frame into time series if there is no DATE? [Python]

Tags: python, datetime, time-series

I want to ask how do use Python to convert the data frame into time series data if there is no "date" but only number of days for example, a datasets with sales values from day 1 until day 500? Thank You !

**Day    Daily sales**

1       1000

2       299

3       499

.       .

.       .

500       399

Comment: What is your approach?

Comment: Hi, I wish to forecast the next 60 days of sales which is from day 501 to day 561.